# Are we able to create an web application using dmn-js library

Tags: reactjs, dmn

Is there any possible ways to implement to create an web application using dmn-js where we can customise and run the application according ti the business needs. I've tried to run the git hub example. But it is not running properly. It would be great if any one suggest some solid example to run the dmn-js starter code in react application.